# Android create two dialog in one activity

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I'm really interested if I can create two dialogs in Android in same time in one activity. Here is what I want to achieve :  I want to have a circle progress bar with a cancel button and at the bottom of my activity to have a horizontal progress dialog which indicates some calculations. Is there any option to create something like this or similar to this?

Thanks in Advance!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason why the synchronizing bar, progress bar, and cancel button could not be part of the same dialog that has a transparent background.

Answer (score 2):

You can call

```
  ProgressDialog#getWindow#setGravity(...) to change the gravity.
```

So:

```
   ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(AContext, "Test", "On the bottom");
            dialog.getWindow().setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot show multiple dialogs at the same time, however you can create an activity with a [transparent background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android) which looks like two different dialogs.